# validate if documents have same data as I send

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've the following documents in database: (each document is a room with members)

```
[
  {
    "id": "room1",
    "members": [{
      "id": "member1",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "member2",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "member3",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "member4",
      "acks": "XXX",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "room2",
    "members": [{
      "id": "memberA",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberB",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberC",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberD",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberE",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberF",
      "acks": "XXX",
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "room3",
    "members": [{
      "id": "memberX",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberY",
      "acks": "XXX",
    },{
      "id": "memberZ",
      "acks": "XXX",
    }]
  }
]
```

Sending from frontend next data:

```
[{
  "id": "room1"
  "members": ["member1", "member2"]
},{
    "id": "room2"
  "members": ["memberA", "memberB", "memberC", "memberF"]
},{
  "id": "room3"
  "members": ["memberX", "memberY"]
}]
```

I want to check if all members match for each room and return an unique boolean as a response --> True if all match and False if is someone that doesn't match.

This data should return false:

```
[{
  "id": "room1"
  "members": ["memberA", "member2"] //Because memberA is not in room1
},{
  "id": "room2"
  "members": ["memberA", "memberB", "memberC", "memberF"]
},{
  "id": "room3"
  "members": ["memberX", "memberY"]
}]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/E-TFueB_m7g)

Is it possible to achieve it with one query?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a query,

1. Prepare your query request from frontend request

```js
// consider this is your request parameter
let request = [{
  "id": "room1",
  "members": ["member1", "member2"]
},{
    "id": "room2",
  "members": ["memberA", "memberB", "memberC", "memberF"]
},{
  "id": "room3",
  "members": ["memberX", "memberY"]
}];
// prepare query
let query = request.map((r) => {
  return { 
    id: r.id, 
    members: r.members.map((m) => {
      return { "members.id": m }
    })
  }
});
console.log(query)
```

2. Try `countDocuments` function and get total count of rooms with request

```
async function hasRooms (query) {
  let count = await Schema.countDocuments({ $or: query });
  return (count === request.length);
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/peE7s3P0vlD)

3. Use your function

```
console.log(await hasRooms(query));
```